# Execute oracle statement using jsp

Tags: oracle, jsp, jdbc

How can I execute 'conn / as sysdba' using jsp.
Using

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
```

shows java.sql.SQLException: SQL string is not Query?

How can I do it using jsp?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://www.javafaq.nu/java-example-code-134.html

Comment: provide complete error stack trace and value of sql variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`conn` is a SQL*Plus command, not a SQL statement.  So it can only be used in SQL*Plus (or another client tool that happens to have some support for SQL*Plus commands).  You can't use it via JDBC.

`conn / as sysdba` tells SQL*Plus to use operating system authentication to connect to the database as the user `SYS` with the `SYSDBA` role enabled.  Operating system authentication in this case would require that SQL*Plus was being invoked on the server where the database is installed and that the user was logged in as the operating system user "oracle".  It seems exceedingly unlikely that it would be appropriate and/or possible for a JSP page to use operating system authentication like this-- that would, at a minimum, require that the application server that is running your JSP code is installed on the same server that Oracle is installed on and that it is running as the same operating system user as the Oracle database.  Neither of those are particularly likely.  Connecting to the database as `SYS` with the `SYSDBA` role enabled would also be very odd for a JSP page-- it is exceedingly rare that you would want JSP code to be running with those sorts of privileges.  Generally, Oracle databases do not allow connections as `SYS` from anything other than the machine that Oracle is running on because, in general, only a DBA would be logging in with that account and then only to perform a very small set of tasks that actually require that sort of elevated access.

It should be possible to configure Oracle to accept remote connections for the user `SYS` with the `SYSDBA` role.  And it should be possible to configure the connection string in your JSP code to use the appropriate password for that account.  But it would be so exceedingly rare to want to do both, and would open such a substantial security hole, that I would seriously question whether that's really what you want to do.  Can you explain a bit more about the problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, *sql* is the Query, but you need `resultQuery = stmt.executeQuery()` to save the result.

Also, take a look to the driver connection, the name of the machine where the DB is and the user name and password.